# Is there a way I can calculate the total sum from two different tables and subtract from one of the colums in one of the tables?

Tags: mysql

So I have two tables: Customer and Transactions. I am task with doing the following:

"List the customers with their current balance greater than £5000 (at least 1 customer
should have their current balance greater than £5000). The current balance can be calculated by
summing the *opening balance* of the account, all the *incoming transactions* of the account, and
*deducting the outgoing transactions* of the account."

Here are my tables:

Customer:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/AuBNS.png

Transactions:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Rvmp.png

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0):

In the first step, you could calculate the balance based only on transactions grouped by customer:

```
SELECT CustomerID, 
       sum(IncomingTransactions - OutgoingTransactions) AS balance
  FROM Transactions
 GROUP BY CustomerID;
```

The next step is to join the results of this query with the Customer table. It might happen, that there's a customer without transactions, therefore you should use an outer join.

```
SELECT Customer.*, 
       OpeningBalance - COALESCE(balance, 0) AS balance
  FROM Customer LEFT JOIN 
       (SELECT CustomerID, 
               sum(IncomingTransactions - OutgoingTransactions) AS balance
          FROM Transactions
         GROUP BY CustomerID) balances 
  ON Customer.CustomerID = balances.CustomerID;
```

The LEFT JOIN ensures that you'll find each Customer in the result. If there's no transaction for a Customer, the columns of the joined table (Transactions) will be NULL. The COALESCE in the SELECT clause turns NULL-values INTO 0.